# Network automation: Difference between Salt and ONOS

Tags: networking, automation, salt-stack, opendaylight

What is the difference between 'networking operating systems' like ONOS, ONAP, Opendaylight and 'configuration management' platforms like Salt, Ansible, Puppet? More specifically, when would I choose one over the other? I have done some research on all these, and as far as I can tell, the configuration management platforms are, as the name implies, for configuring the network, and the operating system platforms are an actual software defined network that can also configure networks/networking devices plus more.

Answer (score 3):

You're really talking about 3 different things.
OpenDaylight and ONOS are network controller platforms.  While ONOS is starting to become feature parity with OpenDaylight, OpenDaylight is more widely deployed (over 1 billion people in production using it) and more supported.

ONAP is a is used to design, create, orchestrate, monitor, and perform life cycle management of open source and commercial VNFs and legacy networks. ONAP uses OpenDaylight MD-SAL at it's core.

I don't have much experience with SALT but it, Ansible and Puppet are flexible DevOps configuration utilities for managing users, services and general automation.

Comment: OpenDaylight also has a much larger and more active development community than ONOS.

Comment: That's what I meant by more supported.  :)

Comment: Thank you, I think I am starting to get a better understanding, however I am not an expert in networking so I am still unsure of the practical applications. Ultimately my goal is to simplify creation and operation of networks, specifically configuring and monitoring devices (possibly 100s, or thousands) and possibly implementing an SD-WAN in the future. Which platform would you recommend?

Comment: That depends on your needs.

Comment: However, you could start by learning more about OPNFV and OpenDaylight.